# Query database in blackberry

Tags: sqlite, blackberry, geolocation, gps, location

I am working on a BlackBerry application that is fetching the current location coordinates. I need to pass these coordinates (latitude and longitude) to a database and query the street, city and country that correspond to these coordinates. I have no idea how this can be done. I have googled for some tutorials, examples and articles but in vain. Can anybody direct me in the right direction how this can be done?

I have a text file with all the data. How should I create a database and populate the tables with the data from my text file? This database to be created should be packaged with the app and not in the SD card. I then want to query this database accordingly and fetch the street, city and country that correspond to these coordinates.

Comment: What is a `.jet` file? (The Microsoft Jet DB Engine (which does *not* run on BlackBerry) used `.mdb` files.)

Comment: @CL yes I read about it. I will edit my question. I have a text file with all the data. How should I create a database and populate the tables with the data from my text file? This database to be created should be packaged with the app and not in the SD card. I then want to query this database accordingly.

Comment: RIM [has disabled R-trees](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/Working_with_SQLite_databases_1219779_11.jsp), so you won't be able to do efficient geographic lookups with SQLite.

Comment: @CL what do you suggest then? What will be the most efficient way for reverse geocoding then? I was hoping, with a local database, I can get the location without depending on any internet connection.

Comment: Not all devices allow to create database on the device memory, on certain devices the database has to be created on the SD card (please refer [link]( http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/data_storage-summary.html). If you are ok with that, let me know, i can suggested an approach as i have worked on something very similiar